# Angular, pulling information from 2 different modules into one (or a separate module)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have broken up an app into separate modules and am trying to pull information from the serrate modules into one place essentially. Right now it's just some variables in controllers within a controller in each module. I was thinking I could just dump them in a div with an id and grab the value with jquery  - as they are already displayed on the same page, but if at all possible, I would love to keep the purely angular.

So - what I have is 2 separate modules on the same page, each has a connected controller and a value inside of

```
$scope.myValue = 1;
```

which is then displayed on the page. I would like to be able to press a button, which I would prefer to be in a separate module (however it's ok for now if it's in one of the two, and collect the values of each variable in one place to work with. I am wondering if there is a (relatively) simple way to do this in angular. Thanks for reading!

Edit - looking for communication between modules.

Comment: why you dont `$emit` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to pass some data:

On module 1:

```
  $rootScope.$emit('DataFromModule1', data)
  $rootScope.$on('DataFromModule2', function(event, data){
      // Do something with the data
  }
```

On module 2:

```
  $rootScope.$emit('DataFromModule2', data)
  $rootScope.$on('DataFromModule1', function(event, data){
      // Do something with the data
  }
```

Depending on how your modules are placed you may be able to use `$scope` inheritance and two-way data binding.

Comment: @ajmajmajma if you emit from `$rootScope`  should be fine.

Comment: Angular is intended to be loaded / bootstrapped once and only once. You should have a super module that depends on the 2 modules you created. Bootstrap multiple disjoint modules into the same page will only cause issue and will never work as expected.

Comment: @ajmajmajma  It really depends on how you structure your code, but with the info that you provided on the question `$emit` was the first thing I thought. If you want you can provide a bit more code :) if there is a more specific use case.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis If he is bootstraping different modules in the same page then each bootstrap with have a different $rootScope.

Comment: @Enzey yes, he should inject the modules inside his app ( the super-model that you refered)

Comment: as @Enzey has mentioned, they are bootstrapped separate ( unfortunately I have to build like this)

Comment: @ajmajmajma you are not able to inject them in your app's config? having them in the same page and create a communication between them with workarounds will only cause problems. And your code will not be easily maintainable. You can provide a bit more code, maybe we can help :)

Comment: Separately bootstrapped modules, the idea is they are being worked on on a big team so they can be modular, and most of the time they are entirely seperate. In this case I would just like to send a little bit of information between them.